# Use 2 different FormRequests in a single controller

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

Is it possible to use 2 different FormRequest validations in a single Controller, one for `store` and the other for `index`, how?

I used `method()` to returns different validations from `rules()`, ex:

```
public function rules()
{

    if($this->method() == 'GET')
    {
        return [
            'customer' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }

    if($this->method() == 'POST')
    {
        return [
            'author' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

but looks very uncomfortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 different Formrequest in one controller.

I do it as following

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function index(ManagePostRequest $request){
       // your code goes here
    }

    public function create(CreatePostRequest $request){
       // your code goes here
    }

    public function store(StorePostRequest $request){
       // your code goes here
    }
}
```

So according to the method you can have different `rules` in form request. Also you can use them for `authorize` the method.

Hope this is what you were asking as the question was a little unclear to me.